# Changing content of a dropdown list while it's open?

Tags: javascript, browser, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list populated with some items. When the user selects one of them, I would like the dropdown list to stay open and be repopulated with new items. The user then selects one of these and finally the dropdown closes.

Can it be done in JavaScript? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without replacing the native control with [a custom one](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/).

Comment: @Thomas A custom control is made with CSS/JavaScript - on the click handler of an item, you'd simply not hide the options and then add the additional options.

Comment: How is javascript going to change the contents of the control while the droplist is open? What will indicate to the browser to repaint the screen with new stuff if the user does not move their mouse?

Comment: @Thomas The options in the custom control are probably `li` elements, so simply append one. I don't think you've understood my suggestion properly.

Answer (score 1):

For science! I've created an alternative answer to test this. You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XLZB/) that contains this HTML:

```html
<select id="y">
    <option>click to open dropdown</option>
    <option>do not choose this!</option>
</select>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
var t = 10;

var x = window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log(--t);
    if (t === 0) { act(); }
}, 1000);

function act() {
    var select = document.getElementById('y');
    var newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.innerHTML = "this option will not appear if the select is open while it's added";
    select.appendChild(newOption);
}
```

If you open the dropdown and *keep it opened* until the timer expires, you will see the following behavior:

- **✗ Chrome 29**: option not visible until reopen + dropdown accomodates for width of new option;
- **✗ IE10/9/8**: same as Chrome 29 + it forcibly collapses the opened dropdown
- **✓ Firefox 23**: adds option without need for reopen + adjusts width for new option

Comment: IE's behavior is still acceptable, or at least, it's less confusing for the user than Chrome's behavior. Any suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: BTW, I just reported that as a Chrome bug. Thanks for the fiddle, it saved me some time.