# Load select options on demand with preserving the select state from beforeload

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-select

To begin with, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgNRn/2/) that shows my point.

I have a simple form with a select field. At first I have pre-loaded only one option that is chosen and I want to load the rest of the options on clicking on the select field. That works fine except for the fact that right on loading these options into the observableArray of options, the 'Choose' default option-caption is taken even though I save the choice before loading and then I try to restore it.

The script is like

```
(function() {

    function COption(id, name) {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    var Options = {
        List: ko.observableArray([
            new COption(1, "opt1")
        ]),
        Loaded: false
    }

    var Choice = ko.observable(1);

    function LoadOptions() {
        var opts = [
            new COption(1, "opt1"),
            new COption(2, "opt2"),
            new COption(3, "opt3")
        ];
        // Save current select state
        var currentChoice = Choice();
        console.log("the choice from before load is " + currentChoice);

        // Prevent loading on each click
        if (!Options.Loaded) {
        // Act as if it was an ajax request
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                Options.List(opts);
                Options.Loaded = true;
                // Bring back the state from beforeload
                Choice(currentChoice);
            }, 100);
        }
    }

    function ChangeOption() {

        var index = 1;
        if (Options.List()[index]) {
            console.log("the choice id is now " + Choice());
            Choice(Options.List()[index].ID);

            console.log("and now it is " + Choice());
        }
    }

    var vm = {
        Choice: Choice,
        Options: Options,
        LoadOptions: LoadOptions,
        ChangeOption: ChangeOption
    }

    ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("page"));

})();
```

and my view goes

```
<div id = "page">
    <div>
        <select data-bind = "options: Options.List, optionsCaption: 'Choose', optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', value: Choice, click: LoadOptions"></select>
    </div>
    <div>your choice's id: <span data-bind = "text: Choice"></span></div>
    <div>
        <button type = "button" data-bind = "click: ChangeOption">Option 2 please</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have been wondering if such kind of forcing the value change is being followed by the bound select field. Turns out that it is which the button proves (the selected option changes after clicking on 'change option' button).

I believe the key is somewhere in the `Choice(currentChoice);`. This applies the change when used with a button and it does not when options are loaded dynamically.

Is it possible to preserve the selected option?

EDIT:
It turns out that each of browsers (IE, Chrome and FF) that I have (later) tested it behaves in a different manner, i.e.

- Firefox (which the description above is about) is the closest to my goal,
- Chrome does not refresh the select options list in my view while it is opened. It needs to be hidden (clicked out) and then reopened to have loaded options visible. This seems weird comparing to FF,
- IE simply closes (hides) the select options list on loading them. This is clearly not my point.

This is why my question now is more like:

*is it possible to dynamically append options to a select while it is opened (shown)?*

And, unfortunately, I can answer to myself with another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmaster/dnVa7/) that clearly proves that the problem is simple as that: only Firefox adds options while the select is shown.

That makes me ask you:

*what is a cross-browser method to dynamically add/load content into a select menu?*

... and again here is the answer: **there is no such possibility** ([proper explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347672/changing-content-of-a-dropdown-list-while-its-open)). So now I am into own select-like control. Over 'n out

Comment: I'm confused. Behavior for me is as follows. At the start "opt1" is selected. I click the dropdown. Nothing visually happens, "opt1" remains selected. I click elsewhere. Nothing happens, "opt1" remains selected. I re-open the dropdown, "opt1" remains selected, and now I also see "opt2" and "opt3". From your question I take it you see different behavior?

Comment: PS. The fiddle is great, but it'd be appreciated if you add the (relevant bits of) code to your question as well. That way if the link rots or jsfiddle goes down your question can still be useful to others with the same issue.

Comment: @Jeroen Okay, I just thought the fiddles are enough everytime. Anyway the first mistake I made with that is the fact that I had only tested that in FF and it is the behavior of FF I have described . It turns out that each FF, Chrome and IE acts different (Chrome loads the options into the array but does not refresh the select while it is open and IE is something between: it opens for a while and on loading options into the array closes the select) but the FF is closest to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense now. Not sure if it's possible. There's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5347672/419956) on adding options to a select while it's open. Zero upvotes on Q and A, but the A may be right nonetheless...

Comment: Either the link from the answer is dead or .. I dunno. I just cannot load that link. Still this pretty much explains my doubts. Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably referred to the "Select2" and "Chosen" jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347672/changing-content-of-a-dropdown-list-while-its-open) that suggests that adding options to a select while it's open isn't quite possible in a good cross-browser way.

The question and answer both have 0 upvotes but I think they're right nonetheless. You know what, I think I'll even go about and [let empiricism do its thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622499/419956) (Chrome & IE10/9/8 will fail, FF will be okay).

This would mean you'd have to replace regular dropdowns with something like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or the [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) jQuery plugin.

Comment: Tried to find some controls like this but failed. Thank you for providing these links, I am going to look at them closer. I am kinda afraid that I am going to replace my knockout.js approach with something more complex but still it is my only option and I will give it a try. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I tried to throw a fiddle together that does things using Select2, but it's not trivial (though probably very possible). You may either need to [forcibly reload](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/788) or create a custom select2-binding to manipulate the select2 data directly.

Comment: I believe I have provided such a fiddle above too which proves the power of FF. Still I am going to dive into both APIs and take the more binding-like control. Anyway it sucks that such a simple thing is not that easy (never expected dynamic selects to need be custom)