# Angularjs <select> not resizing height when ng-options updated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

I'm facing this issue with trying to dynamically load data (i.e `ng-options`) for a drop down on `ng-click`.

So, basically when the page loads, I have the `ng-model` available on page load and I add that to `ng-options` in a `<select>`, that's the only `ng-option` available at page load. Then on `<select ng-click="updateNgOptions()"` I have to make an api call and repopulate `ng-options`.

**My problem is** that when `ng-options` are repopulated, the `<select>` height is not increased. I have to click out of `<select>` and click again for `<select>` height to appear properly.

See below images:

**When I click for the first time, ng-options changed but dd not resize**

[image]

**When I focus-out and click on the drop down again it re sizes**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the different ways browser engines render html. Here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347672/changing-content-of-a-dropdown-list-while-its-open), outside the context of angular. It works OK only in Firefox, for Chrome you need to close and open the ddl and IE closes the ddl automatically.

I created an [angular example](http://plnkr.co/edit/v3mIfgXgEQ1Fvmkx6Y14?p=preview), which you can try out for yourself. The logic is extracted in a separate directive for better readability.

```
<custom-ddl ng-model="selected" options="ddlOptions" more-options-callback="getMoreOptions"></custom-ddl>
```

Comment: So there's no way to force the browser to re render html for that <select> control once ng-options are updated on <select's> ng-click ? I've tried using $compile service to re compile element.children()  but didn't help. I'm forced to use ng-mouseenter which gets the ng-options ready for <select> before user clicks the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this following code:

```
$timeout(function() {
                    $(event.target).css({height: 'auto'});
                });
```

in `updateNgOptions` function.